# Shrink matrix with realloc

Tags: c, dynamic, realloc, calloc

I am currently trying to understand how dynamic memory allocation works.
I have this code:

```
int main()
{
    int **mat, i;

    mat = calloc(3, sizeof(int*));
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        mat[i] = calloc(3, sizeof(int));

    mat = realloc(mat, 1*sizeof(int*));
    for(i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        mat[i] = realloc(mat[i], 1*sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        free(mat[i]);
    free(mat);

    return 0;
}
```

I have checked with valgrind for memory leaks:

```
 24 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
 at 0x4C2C975: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:711)
 by 0x400605: main (main.c:10)

LEAK SUMMARY:
  definitely lost: 24 bytes in 2 blocks
  indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
  still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
     suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

The leaks don't occur if I reallocate to n*sizeof(int) where n > 1. 
Why is this happening?

Comment: When you reduce the `mat` array size you have lost some of the `mat[i]` pointers. Namely `mat[1]` and `mat[2]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you reduce the `mat` array size you have lost some of the `mat[i]` pointers. Namely `mat[1]` and `mat[2]`. You need to manually `free` any pointers that will be lost during the shrink `realloc` before doing the `realloc`.